# "gem install rails" fails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to manually install rails, but have encountered the following error:

```
c:\Ruby193\bin>gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can this be solved?

The steps I followed so far:

- I installed Ruby from here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/,
  running the Ruby 1.9.3-p545 from the RubyInstaller section. (into
  C:\Ruby193)
- I installed also (for use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3): the
  DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe into C:\RubyDevKit.
- I went to RubyDevKit in cmd and typed:

> dir dk.rb
>   ruby dk.rb init
>   ruby dk.rb install

- I launched irb (typed irb in C:\RubyDevKit) to confirm ruby
  works and it does.

Comment: Umm are you connected to the internet?

Comment: yes, I am connected to the internet, mu. In fact, I just tried now to manually download `http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz` by typing this in my browser and it worked. But still, my Rails installation fails when I enter `gem install rails` as described above. Is there something I am missing? Need to install rails.

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16996318/1860929).

Answer (score -1):

I am right now faced with this problem

Reset DNS cache solved that problem for me
(Run "ipconfig /flushdns" from cmd shell)