# Error while installing rails and starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm totally new to rails. I downloaded rails package from railsinstaller.org and installed it. While starting server, i got this error

"Could not find uglifier..."

Then i tried bundle install. It is not working.
[image]

Then i totally uninstalled it and installed only ruby from rubyinstaller.org. Ruby is working fine. When i tried "gem install rails", i'm getting this error

"could not download data from rubygems.org"

**What i tried**

1) I downloaded the rails-4.1.7.gem and tried installing it locally as show here
[How can I specify a local gem in my Gemfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile)

I tried gem "rails", :path => "D:\rails-4.1.7.gem"

Error: Unknown command rails

2) I tried the solution here
[gem install rails doesn't work due to openssl/ETimedout in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996318/gem-install-rails-doesnt-work-due-to-openssl-etimedout-in-windows)

But getting this exception

[image]

I cannot able to set it up. Please tell how to install rails and start the server. I'm a total newbie to rails.

Comment: If you are using firewall/proxy, you might want to disable that.

Comment: @TusharMaroo Actually, Its not my laptop its companies (work). I cannot disable proxy. So atleast i want to install it locally. I downloaded the gem

Comment: Go to D-drive(or where you have downloaded the gem), run `gem install rails --local` and let me know if this works.

Comment: @TusharMaroo ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)
    package metadata is missing in rails-4.1.7.gem

Comment: I tried to recreate the same issue at my end, but instead of your error i got another error for installing dependencies along with rails gem like active-record etc....also under heading "What i tried" you mentioned you have tried it putting it in Gemfile? but i don't understand if you don't have rails installed, how did you get directories & Gemfile?

Comment: @TusharMaroo Actually i referred to that link and some one edited it. I'm totally new to rails. I want to learn it and trying to install it. I have no idea about much stuff. I tried installing the rails gem locally and it didn't worked. That is what i said there.